# updating string list while typing in textview

Tags: android, textview, textwatcher

I need a list of string be read from server, that list will be give to an adapter for searching suggestion in autocompletetextview while user is typing. In order to see how to use conveniently a textchangelistener I wrote this:

```
TextWatcher tw
= new TextWatcher() {

    @Override
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
            int after) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before,
            int count) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "text has changed!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        // getlist() <-- this calls an AsyncTask instance
    }

};
```

As expected, when I type in a qwerty softkeyboard the toast message is displayed each time a key is pressed and that's ok. But what if the user has a softkeyboard those you have to press the same key two or three times to write a determined letter, for example if you want a 'c' you must press the key '2' three times. I tried the code above and obviously the message is shown three times but it is required only once for each new submitted letter, remember that ultimately the commented asyncstask object would work there and it is power consuming task. Some advice?

Comment: I think you can create a beforeString and actualString and only call the getlist() after you check if !actualString.equals( beforeString ); Also, you should check if the actualString is not white space.

Comment: try giving a delay, before you ask the server for a result 2-3 seconds for each letter should do. users who type this way a lot, usually take less to make up the letter